# Regular Expressions - Name Patterns

Tags: regex, excel, vba, outlook

I'm a beginner when it comes to coding and I'm figuring out right now how to use Regular Expressions.

What I'm doing is extracting data from incoming mails in Outlook 2013. I'm using VBA + RegEx to extract the data I need and consolidate/transfer them to an Excel Worksheet, but my problem is with names. I can figure out what pattern is needed since there's a lot of possible name structures.

Here's a sample email

> ```
> ID: 123456
> Name: Dela Peña, Juan Carlos
> Department: Accounts
> Shift: 10:00 - 18:00
> ```

Here's the what I have in my VBA:

```
.pattern = "(Name[:]+\s*(\w*-\w*)?(\s\w*)?(\s\w*[.]?)?(\s\w*[.]?)?[,]?(\s\w*[.]?)?(\s\w*[.]?)?(\s\w*[.]?))"
```

And here is a list of possible name pattern/combinations that might show up on the incoming mails:

1. Lastname, (Ma.) Givenname (Jr.)
2. Lastname, (Ma.) Givenname Givenname
3. Lastname, (Ma.) Givenname Givenname Givenname
4. lastname-Lastname, (Ma.) Givenname Givenname Givenname
5. Lastname. Lastname (Jr.), (Ma.) Givenname Givenname (Jr.)
6. Last**ñ**ame, (Ma.) Givenname Givenname Givenname - *This is where it gets tricky and I cant seem to find a way to insert it in my RegEx.

Comment: You have told us what the possible input combinations are but not what you want the corresponding out to be.  For each of the 6 cases above you need to tell us what you want the output to be.

Comment: Why not `Name:\s*(.+)`? It should work if all you need is to get all the rest of the *line* after `Name:` and 0+ whitespace chars. Then you may get the value if Group 1 and even split with a comma if need be

Comment: And if you need to separate first and last name: `Name:\s(.+),\s(.+)`

Comment: Use this to learn RegEx: https://regexr.com/
You can paste in your dataset and then modify the regex until it works as desired.

Comment: Thank you guys for all your suggestions! Theyr'e all helpful and I learned new stuff! Also, I just realized that the emails are based on a template so how it appears and how the info are given is always going to be the same. Since the "Name" part will always have a name, I'm going to follow the suggestion below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't try to include all specific patterns. We can't think about them all.

Why don't you use this?

```
(?i)Name:(?:.|[\n\r\t\s])*?(?=[\n\r\t\s]*(?:Department|ID|Shift|Name)[\n\r\t\s]*:|$)
```

[image]

Comment: From my experience, '\s' includes only two unicodes, \u0020 and \u00A0. '\n' and '\r' are different from '\s'. They are called carriage or line returns. '\t' is an inserted tab.

Comment: `\s` means any kind os whitespace i.e. `[ \t\r\n\f\v]`